# Convert PDF file into a preview Image inside react page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, pdf, preview

I'm trying once i upload a PDF to my site to display a lil preview of it instead of a PDF logo or some thing like that.
Would appreciate if someone implemented some thing like that would help me with this problem

Was looking at React-pdf but it as I saw it open a big page of the pdf which I don't want.
Saw pdf2pic which apparently now only used in nodejs

Comment: You have to use a third-party library which is going to read the PDF and generate a preview image. You can do it in your backend for more performance since you upload the PDF there anyway.

Comment: Can you specify which library u had a good experience with?

Comment: The LEADTOOLS toolkit has the `RasterCodecs` class can [load](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/co/rastercodecs-load.html) a PDF as an image in a `RasterImage` object that can be then used to [generate a thumbnail](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/l/rasterimage-createthumbnail.html) image that is suitable as a preview image. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)